# gazebo_ros-config.cmake unknown when compiling hydro

Tags: ros, gazebo-ros, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I am trying to compile hydro for ubuntu 12.04 LTS following [these instructions](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Source) - variant *desktop_full*.

The first 119 packages (out of 259) compile fine but the 120th called *rrbot_gazebo* cannot find the *.cmake* file for *gazebo_ros*. It shows the following error:

```
CMake Error at /home/arennuit/catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):

  Could not find a configuration file for package gazebo_ros.

  Set gazebo_ros_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file
  for gazebo_ros.  The file will have one of the following names:

    gazebo_rosConfig.cmake
    gazebo_ros-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)
```

Any idea of what is going on? I could find any of the 2 *.cmake files indicated anywhere on my system... And I do not seem to find the solution in the internet...

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187291/gazebo_ros-config.cmake-unknown-when-compiling-hydro/) by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 955 on 2014-07-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For my hydro install I have the file `gazebo_rosConfig.cmake` in `install/share/gazebo_ros/cmake/`. Possibly gazebo_ros has not been properly built/installed before the build of `robot_gazebo` has started.

You could try invoking `catkin_make_isolated` with additional `--only-pkg-with-deps gazebo_ros` and after that has finished invoke it again to build everything.

It seems that the `rrbot_gazebo` is missing some `build_depends` in its [package.xml](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_demos/blob/master/rrbot_gazebo/package.xml), but I wounder why you are building this package at all. At some point it seems you are deviating from the tutorial, because for me I don't see `rrbot_gazebo` as part of `desktop_full` on hydro.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2014-07-22**:
Hum it seems catkin_make_isolated somehow compiles all packages in my workspace (and not all all packages from variant desktop_full. So I created a new clean workspace and it compiled. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-07-22**:
Yes catkin_make and catkin_make_isolated build all packages in the workspace by default (this is by design). There are some command line arguments to control this (or did you mean to imply that these arguments failed to work in your case?).

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-07-22**:
Regardsless, the rrbot_gazebo packge is broken and if you actually use it I'm sure the maintainers would welcome a pull request fixing the dependencies. Also, if your problem is solved, you might want to indicate that to everyone by marking the answers as accepted.

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2014-07-22**:
Done.
PS: thanks for the extra precisions